# Oracle Spatial Area Overlap Percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, overlap, oracle-spatial

I am working with 2 tables containing polygons as shown hereunder.
I have many parkingzones and two special areas contained in the dangerareas table.
Some of the parking zones overlap with these areas, my purpose is two know the extent of this overlap as an area overlap percentage per parking.
I want a null results for the not overlaping parkings.
I am working with SQL Oracle Developper. 
I can't figure out why this query is not working. 
(I have adapted the layer names as I can't use the real ones, I hope there is no typo left).
My query returns an error :

> ORA-13011: value is out of range ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line
>   125 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line 1878
>   13011. 00000 -  "value is out of range"

```
db = CITY
Table 1 : parkingzones PK
id_parking
SHAPE

Table 2 : dangerareas DA
id_area
SHAPE

SELECT 
 (area_overlaps/area_zones*100) as pct_overlap

FROM  
(SELECT(SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA 
     (SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(PK.SHAPE,DA.SHAPE,0,05)0,05)) area_overlaps
  FROM CITY.parkingzones PK
       CITY.dangerareas DA),
 (SELECT (SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(PK.SHAPES,0.05)) area_zones ) 
  FROM CITY.parkingzones PK);
```

Comment: Don't use comma in tolerance value. Missing comma in sdo_area, missing comma in from clause....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total parking area:

```
select sum(SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(PK.SHAPES,0.05)) total_parking_area
  FROM CITY.parkingzones PK
```

Total overlapping area:

```
SELECT sum(SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA( 
             SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(PK.SHAPE,DA.SHAPE,0.05),0.05))) total_overlap
  FROM CITY.parkingzones PK
       ,CITY.dangerareas DA
where sdo_anyinteract(PK.shape,DA.shape) = 'TRUE';
```

Overlap per parking (only that have overlap)

```
select (sdo_geom.sdo_area(sdo_geom.sdo_intersection(pk.shape, da.shape, 0.05), 0.05) /
       sdo_geom.sdo_area(pk.shape, 0.05)) * 100 percentage
  from city.parkingzones pk
      ,city.dangerareas  da
 where sdo_anyinteract(pk.shape, da.shape) = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Mmm, this won't solve the problem. I am looking for the overlapping area per parking, not the total overlap. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Added overlap per parking

Comment: Thank you. That works ! 
As i am planning more calculations on the area and overlapping area..  I got my query in the question to work now as well but I am getting percentages above 100%. Any clue why this is ?

Comment: Adapt your query so it shows the parking area and the overlap area numbers and see what you can find.